# "Not all patches could be applied exception" in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am using alfresco 5.0.d and I am just trying to encrypt a property.

I am using this code to get the `metadetaEncyptor` bean:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext();
MetadataEncryptor metadataEncryptor (MetadataEncryptor) ctx.getBean("metadataEncryptor");                       
Serializablede cryptedValue = metadataEncryptor.decrypt(qname,properties.get(qname));
```

In my local the code was working fine but when I just upgrade my local to make equal to production environment (just restore the db and contentstore), I'm getting this exception:

```
04030013 Not all patches could be applied
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?.

Comment: Further up in the logs it should tell you which patches didn't apply, and the stacktrace. What are those?

Comment: thanks to respond mr. Gagravarr i just updated some pics. i hope it will help you to understand the question. i think patch.surfconfig is not applied.   pls help me what should i do for this

Comment: We need to see the full details of the patch error(s) from your `alfresco.log` file